# How to update KendoUI Grids datasource from the controller?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui

I'm trying to update the datasource of the grid using the below code. But I just want to update a specific column and I don't want to reload the whole grid. We have a minimum of 100 records that shows but it took several seconds to load. We have this logic that the user scans a barcode and it will update the column. Right now it loads everything after.

Is it possible just to update a specific column and not to load the whole grid?

```
$("#GridCreateShipment").data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();


 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ProductionShipment>()
          .Name("GridCreateShipment")
          .AutoBind(true)
          .Filterable(filter => filter.Extra(false).Operators(op => op.ForString(str => str.Clear().Contains("Contains"))))
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
         
              columns.Bound(p => p.OrderNo).Title("Order No.").Width(150).Filterable(false);
              columns.Bound(p => p.DetailNum).Title("Line No.").Groupable(false).Encoded(false).Filterable(false).Width(60);
              columns.Bound(p => p.ShipdateString).Title("Ship Date").Groupable(false).Encoded(false).Filterable(false).Width(100);
              columns.Bound(p => p.CustomerName).Title("Customer").Filterable(false).Width(150);
              columns.Bound(p => p.CustomerShipTo).Title("Customer Ship-To").Filterable(false).Width(150);
              columns.Bound(p => p.CustomerPO).Title("PO No.").Filterable(false).Width(90);
              columns.Bound(p => p.ItemId).Title("Item ID").Filterable(false).Width(200);
              columns.Bound(p => p.ItemDescription).Title("Description").Width(300).Filterable(false);
              columns.Bound(p => p.OrigQty).Title("Orig Qty").Filterable(false).Width(100);
              columns.Bound(p => p.QtyProduced).Title("Qty Produced").Filterable(false).Width(100);
              columns.Bound(p => p.QtyLoaded).Title("Qty Loaded").Filterable(false).Width(100);
              //columns.Bound(p => p.Routes).Filterable(false).Width(200);

          })
      
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              //BTG v.1.1.62 
              //Removed
              //.Sort(x=>x.Add("OrderNo").Ascending())
              .Read(read => read.Action("GridFillCreateShipment", "Production").Data("additionalData"))
              

          )

          )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

First you need to get the value as an object from the controller, second get the dataitem/row from the current grid, last using `"dataItem.set()"` to change the value of the column(this will update the view for your grid as well and not reloading the entire grid)

```
var data = //controller return;
var grid = $("#GridCreateShipment").data("kendoGrid");
var dataItem = grid.dataSource.get(data.ItemId);
dataItem.set("Customer","Devina");
```

You could try this solution, but I still suggest you to keep all records updated every time you make changes, if you don't want to reload the entire (100 records) every time, you could limit the records that is displaying on current grid (Use pageSize or Pagination ) and this will only loads the # of records for that pageSize.

Hope this answers your question.